Is there a way to access my phone data from the boot menu or to fix an Android OS without factory reset? Or even to stop the restart from happening?
My Motorola One Hyper phone starts, finishes the boot animation, then I unlock it with the PIN number, then it opens and there is the problem. It stays on for about 5 to 10 seconds where I can use it, and then a black screen covers whatever I'm doing that says it is resetting to factory reset and restarting. It loads for a few seconds and reboots. When it starts, it goes directly to recover where it shows me only two options.

Restart

Factory reset


I need to access the data on the phone before I can factory reset. I don't care about saving the current installation, but before resetting, I need to extract my data. I would like to be able to explore the phone before a factory reset.
I can use the phone "normally" for those few seconds it turns on, I can access menus and enable or disable options (I could manage to enter developer mode).
I tried safe mode but it is the same.
I tried the Rescue and Smart Assistant tool, but it also requires the phone to be on the main screen and with the app opened and that is precisely my issue.
Any input or suggestion on how to access the data or what to try would be appreciated. Since I don't know if the device is rooted nor I have done anything of the sort, I assume it is not.
Maybe even a process I can stop or something to just be able to keep the phone on enough to browse the files and then factory reset or reinstall or update firmware.

Have you tried if the "black screen" / crash also happens if you connect the phone to a charger (not to a computer, to a real charger that provides at least 2A @ 5V). If it then does not crash the problem is your battery. If it still crahes it is something totally different.

I tried indeed in several chargers. The one included with the phone power charges but I also tried with other that have that rating or even higher. The black screen that I mention is not entirely black. It is like a full screen information dialog, not like a black screen of death. You can faintly see the phone screen while the message of restarting is displaying. Thank you for your reply. I keep trying anything and I will try whatever I can.
